# Faced error for installing pccapg2 for pathm3.12 in the Linux (ubuntu) server

Tags: python, linux, psycopg2, python-3.12

I want to install psycopg2 for Python 3.12 on Ubuntu.

For installation, I am using the command:

```
> python3.12 -m pip install psycopg2
```

But it shows this error:

```py
Collecting psycopg2 Downloading psycopg2-2.9.9.tar.gz (384 kB) ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 384.9/384.9 kB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00 
Installing build dependencies ... done Getting requirements to build wheel ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [21 lines of output] running egg_info writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

  Error: pg_config executable not found.

  pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
  containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
  option:

      python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

  or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

  If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
  'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

How can I solve the error? What can I do?